How to disable inlay hints in DataGrip's Database Explorer
As the title suggest I am looking for a way to disable "inlay hints" in Database Explorer. I have tried to disable hints globally with no success.
To be more precise I am not talking about inlay hints in the editor tab but in the Database Explorer. See the image below:


Looks like it's not possible for now. I created a feature request for it https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-21832/Disable-hints-for-objects-in-Database-Explorer
Please subscribe to receive updates
